# cBlas performance + speed

Tags: c++, c, blas

I have used cBLAS and done some speed tests and I was surprised with the results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include  <GL/glfw.h>

    void matriz_matriz(float *matriz1,float *matriz2,float *matrizr){
      matrizr[0]  = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[8]*matriz2[2])  +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[3]);
      matrizr[1]  = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[9]*matriz2[2])  +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[3]);
      matrizr[2]  = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[10]*matriz2[2]) +(matriz1[14]*matriz2[3]);
      matrizr[3]  = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[0])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[1])  +(matriz1[11]*matriz2[2]) +(matriz1[15]*matriz2[3]);

      matrizr[4]  = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[8]*matriz2[6])  +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[7]);
      matrizr[5]  = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[9]*matriz2[6])  +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[7]);
      matrizr[6]  = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[10]*matriz2[6]) +(matriz1[14]*matriz2[7]);
      matrizr[7]  = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[4])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[5])  +(matriz1[11]*matriz2[6]) +(matriz1[15]*matriz2[7]);

      matrizr[8]  = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[8]*matriz2[10]) +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[11]);
      matrizr[9]  = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[9]*matriz2[10]) +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[11]);
      matrizr[10] = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[10]*matriz2[10])+(matriz1[14]*matriz2[11]);
      matrizr[11] = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[8])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[9])  +(matriz1[11]*matriz2[10])+(matriz1[15]*matriz2[11]);

      matrizr[12] = (matriz1[0]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[4]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[8]*matriz2[14]) +(matriz1[12]*matriz2[15]);
      matrizr[13] = (matriz1[1]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[5]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[9]*matriz2[14]) +(matriz1[13]*matriz2[15]);
      matrizr[14] = (matriz1[2]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[6]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[10]*matriz2[14])+(matriz1[14]*matriz2[15]);
      matrizr[15] = (matriz1[3]*matriz2[12])+(matriz1[7]*matriz2[13])+(matriz1[11]*matriz2[14])+(matriz1[15]*matriz2[15]);
    }


    int main(){
      int i;
      double tiempo1;
      double tiempo2;

      glfwInit();

      float *mat0 = NULL;
      float *mat1 = NULL;
      float *mat2 = NULL;

      mat0  = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
      mat1  = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
      mat2  = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));

      mat0[0]  =  1.0;
      mat0[1]  =  0.0;
      mat0[2]  =  0.0;
      mat0[3]  =  0.0;
      mat0[4]  =  0.0;
      mat0[5]  =  1.0;
      mat0[6]  =  0.0;
      mat0[7]  =  0.0;
      mat0[8]  =  0.0;
      mat0[9]  =  0.0;
      mat0[10] =  1.0;
      mat0[11] =  0.0;
      mat0[12] =  3.281897;
      mat0[13] =  4.714289;
      mat0[14] =  5.124306;
      mat0[15] =  1.0;

      mat1[0]  =  1.0;
      mat1[1]  =  0.0;
      mat1[2]  =  0.0;
      mat1[3]  =  0.0;
      mat1[4]  =  0.0;
      mat1[5]  =  0.924752;
      mat1[6]  =  0.380570;
      mat1[7]  =  0.0;
      mat1[8]  =  0.0;
      mat1[9]  = -0.380570;
      mat1[10] =  0.924752;
      mat1[11] =  0.0;
      mat1[12] =  0.0;
      mat1[13] =  0.0;
      mat1[14] =  0.0;
      mat1[15] =  1.0;

      mat2[0]  =  1.0;
      mat2[1]  =  0.0;
      mat2[2]  =  0.0;
      mat2[3]  =  0.0;
      mat2[4]  =  0.0;
      mat2[5]  =  1.0;
      mat2[6]  =  0.0;
      mat2[7]  =  0.0;
      mat2[8]  =  0.0;
      mat2[9]  =  0.0;
      mat2[10] =  1.0;
      mat2[11] =  0.0;
      mat2[12] =  0.0;
      mat2[13] =  0.0;
      mat2[14] =  0.0;
      mat2[15] =  1.0;

       tiempo1 = glfwGetTime();

       for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
        matriz_matriz(mat0,mat1,mat2);
        //cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,4,4,4,1.0f,mat0,4,mat1,4,0.0f,mat2,4);
       }

      tiempo2 = glfwGetTime();
      printf("Tiempo total: %f\n",tiempo2-tiempo1);

      for(i=0;i<16;i++)printf("valor[%i]: %f\n",i,mat2[i]);

      free(mat0);
      free(mat1);
      free(mat2);

      system("pause");

      glfwTerminate();
      return 0;
    }
```

If I use the function `cblas_sgemm (...)` tiempo2 - tiempo1 returns the value of `0.096924`, but if I use my own function (`matriz_matriz(...)`) tiempo2 - tiempo1 returns the value of `0.046271`

What happens? My function is faster than Cblas.

This test was tested on a PC with Pentium 3 processor. Can anyone tell me what happens?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try it with a 1000 x 1000 matrix ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timing results are valid. Your matriz_matriz function uses full unrolling for matrix-matrix multiplication. This is a standard optimization technique. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding.

The problem is that your function works only for 4X4 matrices. If you try to create a general multiplication function then you have to use `for` loops. Then execution time will increase.

For optimized BLAS routines please refer to ATLAS and OpenBLAS libraries.

- http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.openblas.net/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's really not my intention to create a function of "general purpose". The function that I'm going to use for calculation of the matrices in the skinning of my model. :-)